# Query for Updates in database when One of the Column is affected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with column as points,ranking and some others.  When I change the points in the database is it possible to rank all the records based on updated data.  I am not entering ranks it should be calculated every time when I change the Points column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql rank function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function) and many many others

Comment: Alternatively to a search like: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+rank

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest do not do any calculations in the DB, it should be done at the Sever. You may do (on MYSQL):

```
SELECT points FROM TABLE ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Then on the server you have a descending order list of points with each you can associate a Rank.

DB is best kept as away as possible from calculations.

Comment: But i  have one more column name as Ranking which holds the ranking of teams based on points so how will i update the rankings once points are changed

Comment: Remove that coloumn. You can always populate ranking after fetching points from the server.